# How to Calculate Batting Index and Bowling Index?

Tags: cricket, statistics

I was wishing to understand the formula to use to calculate the Batting Index and Bowling Index in Cricket.
This is for limited overs cricket (50 overs) for my club players

Comment: The batting index is calculated by adding the strike rate and the average runs.

Comment: What is batting/bowling index? Can you provide an example?

Comment: never heard these terms before

Comment: A batting index for limited-overs cricket http://www.espncricinfo.com/thestands/content/story/752205.html

Answer (score 1):

The Bowling index is the Bowlers average multiplied by runs conceeded per ball (This calculation is mentioned in this [article](http://www.espncricinfo.com/magazine/content/story/541322.html)).

The Batting index (at least as defined by NatWest T20) is the sum of the batsmans run rate and his strike rate. (As mentioned in this [article](http://www.espncricinfo.com/thestands/content/story/752205.html)).

Answer (score 0):

**Batting Index:**
The batting index is the Strike Rate multiplied by the Average Runs then that is divided by 50

BI = ((SR*AVG)/50)

E.g.
The batting index of a player with SR of 123.4 and an average of 45.33 runs:

(123.4*45.33)/50 = 112 (rounded)

As for Bowlers Index, I'm not sure that exists. Or at least I haven't seen it.

Answer (score 0):

Batting index, at least in the matches telecasted by skysports (the recent t20 between England and India) is a simple addition of a batsman's average and strike rate.

So if a batsman has an average of 23 and a strike rate of 120 , his batting index will be 143.

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/cricket/international/england/10841469/England-should-continue-placing-great-faith-in-statistics-under-Peter-Moores.html

In the link above there is aline explaining what I said.